# Keras Data Augmentation giving worse perf in example given DL with Keras book

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have been following the example given in the book "Deep Learning with Keras" by Gulli and Pal. In chapter 3 "Improving the CIFAR-10 performance with data augmentation", I can't reproduce anywhere near its stated test accuracy of about 0.78. In fact, I got this:

```
Epoch 48/50
390/390 [==============================] - 946s 2s/step - loss: 1.2158 - acc: 0.5853

Epoch 49/50
390/390 [==============================] - 944s 2s/step - loss: 1.2233 - acc: 0.5845

Epoch 50/50
390/390 [==============================] - 946s 2s/step - loss: 1.2382 - acc: 0.5793
```

Anyone tried this? and can offer insight. I observed that the train accuracy is actually going down half way through the computation.

This is as if the model ability to model the data is being challenged. The book has just code snippets which isn't complete enough to run on its own, you have to look at the github to get all the code. I am "debugging" as to why I can't reproduce the book result. I will update this more later.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a couple of reasons, the example data generator doesn’t seem to rescale by 1/255. also, adding data augmentation will require more epochs for convergence.

Alternatively, I found the example in Chollet’s book “Deep Learning with Python” is working as advertised and I was able to reproduce that one.